# How to format and display set inside a list in bottle's template？

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

**current situation**

index_template.tpl

```
{{links}}
```

Output result

```
[{'http://www.oreilly.com/careers/', 'http://www.oreilly.com/about/editorial_independence.html', 'https://cdn.oreillystatic.com/pdf/oreilly_high_performance_organizations_whitepaper.pdf', 'https://www.youtube.com/user/OreillyMedia', 'https://www.safaribooksonline.com/?utm_medium=content&amp;utm_source=oreilly.com&amp;utm_campaign=lgen&amp;utm_content=20170601+nav'}, {'http://www.oreilly.com/careers/', 'http://www.oreilly.com/about/editorial_independence.html'}, {'http://www.oreilly.com/careers/', 'http://www.oreilly.com/about/editorial_independence.html', 'https://cdn.oreillystatic.com/pdf/oreilly_high_performance_organizations_whitepaper.pdf', 'https://www.youtube.com/user/OreillyMedia'}]
```

---

**I created the following code, but how can I display the hierarchy more easily in a more easy-to-understand way by separating it with ","?**

index_template.tpl

```
<html>
   <ul>
       %for item in links:
         <li>{{item}}</li>
       %end
   </ul>
</html>
```

Output result

```
・{'http://www.oreilly.com/careers/', 'http://www.oreilly.com/about/editorial_independence.html', 'https://cdn.oreillystatic.com/pdf/oreilly_high_performance_organizations_whitepaper.pdf', 'https://www.youtube.com/user/OreillyMedia', 'https://www.safaribooksonline.com/?utm_medium=content&amp;utm_source=oreilly.com&amp;utm_campaign=lgen&amp;utm_content=20170601+nav'}
・{'http://www.oreilly.com/careers/', 'http://www.oreilly.com/about/editorial_independence.html'} 
・{'http://www.oreilly.com/careers/', 'http://www.oreilly.com/about/editorial_independence.html', 'https://cdn.oreillystatic.com/pdf/oreilly_high_performance_organizations_whitepaper.pdf', 'https://www.youtube.com/user/OreillyMedia'}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a `dict`? Looks like a `set` inside a `list`. In any case, bottle's built-in template language allows to iterate over collections using Python-like syntax.

Comment: set inside a list is not a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `links` object is a `list` of `set`s, which you can iterate over using nested `for`-loops:

```
<html>
    <ul>
    % for link in links:
        % for item in link:
        <li>{{item}}</li>
        % end
    % end  
    </ul>
</html>
```

output:

> - https://www.safaribooksonline.com/?utm_medium=content&amp;utm_source=oreilly.com&amp;utm_campaign=lgen&amp;utm_content=20170601+nav
> - https://www.youtube.com/user/OreillyMedia
> - http://www.oreilly.com/about/editorial_independence.html
> - http://www.oreilly.com/careers/
> - https://cdn.oreillystatic.com/pdf/oreilly_high_performance_organizations_whitepaper.pdf
> - http://www.oreilly.com/careers/
> - http://www.oreilly.com/about/editorial_independence.html
> - https://www.youtube.com/user/OreillyMedia
> - http://www.oreilly.com/careers/
> - http://www.oreilly.com/about/editorial_independence.html
> - https://cdn.oreillystatic.com/pdf/oreilly_high_performance_organizations_whitepaper.pdf